# Download FTP usando c#

Tags: c#, .net

Estou tentando efetuar um download de um servidor FTP. O problema é o seguinte:

Eu preciso de uma forma de particionar o arquivo que estou baixando. Para que ele seja baixado parte por parte e não completo de uma vez. Fazendo de forma assíncrona também não funciona para o meu caso, pois também seria baixado todo...

Utilizando das classes `FtpWebRequest` e `FtpWebResponse` é possível definir (em bytes) de que parte do arquivo irá começar o download, através da propriedade `.ContentOffset` da classe `FtpWebRequest`. Mesmo assim, não existe, ou pelo menos não conheço alguma propriedade que delimite o quanto deste arquivo será baixado. Segue o código, para ilustração, abaixo:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endereco);

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

request.ContentOffset = 5000; //inicia o download desta posicao.

using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stm = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(LocalArquivo, FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            while (true)
            {
                int read = stm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    return;
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tentei também usando a classe WebClient. Mas também não obtive sucesso. Através do evento DownloadProgressChanged é possível se obter a quantidade de bytes que já foi baixada através da propriedade .BytesReceived da DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs.Segue o código, para ilustração, abaixo:

```
using (WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
{

  cliente.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

  cliente.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);

  Uri url = new Uri(endereco);

  cliente.DownloadFileAsync(url, LocalArquivo);

}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        long progresso = e.BytesReceived; //numero de bytes ja baixados...
    }
```

Gostaria de alguma dica ou instrução de como devo executar esse download de forma a não baixar o arquivo completo, mas sim, em partes.

desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: No seu lugar, eu faria uma lista de `Task<MemoryStream>` e dispararia algumas *threads* com o procedimento de download, mas não estou seguro se o FTP suporta isso. Não guardaria em *buffer* porque o offset é bastante curto. Ou ainda, se preferir, usaria `Task<FileStream>` com gravação de arquivos temporários. De fato, não é uma solução simples.

Comment: Você controla quanto você baixa da conexão FTP a partir da stream retornada por `response.GetResponseStream()`. Por exemplo, se você só quiser ler 5000 bytes, então só solicite esta quantidade de bytes. Note que a solução não é simplesmente `stm.Read(buffer, 0, 5000)`, pois a stream pode retornar menos bytes que a quantidade que você requisitou (você precisa de um loop até ter a quantidade desejada, ou que Stream.Read retorne 0).

Answer (score 2):

Adicione o Metódo AddRange, para pegar somente uma parte do arquivo.

```
request.AddRange(0, 999);
```

Nó código acima vc irá obter os 1000 primeiros bytes do arquivo.